# Definition of height of ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I see two different definitions for height of the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ (that is not a prime ideal)

One is defined as

$$ ht( \mathfrak{a} ) = \inf_{ \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{p} } ht (\mathfrak{p}) $$

where $\mathfrak{p}$ is restricted to prime ideal.

The other is

$$ ht( \mathfrak{a} ) = \min_{ \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{p} } ht (\mathfrak{p}) $$

Obviously the latter assumes that there is $\mathfrak{p}$ that attains the minimum. My questions is, shouldn't there always be $\mathfrak{p}$ that attains the minimum? In other words, why put it as $\inf$ instead of $\min$?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $\Bbb N$ well-ordered?

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\inf$ is not wrong. Writing $\min$ just emphatizes that the minimum is attained.